# Django - Custom Filter to check if File exists

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

I made this custom filter to check if an image exists or not:

```
from django import template
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='file_exists')
def file_exists(filepath):
    if default_storage.exists(filepath):
        return filepath
    else:
        index = filepath.rfind('/')
        new_filepath = filepath[:index] + '/image.png'
        return new_filepath
```

And I used this in the template like this:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/{{ book.imageurl }}|file_exists" alt="{{book.title}} Cover Photo">
```

But it doesn't work. And I have no idea why.

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? What does it return?

Comment: I get `http://localhost:8000/static/images/ios.png|file_exists` in url of image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not applying the filter because `|file_exists` is outside of `{{}}`. Try this:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/{{ book.imageurl|file_exists }}" alt="{{book.title}} Cover Photo">
```

Or, if you want to apply `file_exists` to the whole image url, try this:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL|add:'images/'|add:book.imageurl|file_exists }}" alt="{{book.title}} Cover Photo">
```

Comment: I want the filter to get `{{ STATIC_URL }}images/{{ book.imageurl }}`.  and not just `{{book.imageurl}}`.Is it possible?

Comment: I tried your first method and changed filter to `.exists('appname/static/images/'+DataIReceived)` and `.exists('static/images/'+DataIReceived)` but in both cases django can't find file and I get 'image.png' back. What should be the relative path?

Comment: Also, I think, that you should pass an absolute path to `exists`, try constructing it from the `os.path.join(<project root>, <image path>)`.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I used a dirty method to get absolute path and I will have to fix is soon (`os.path.join` was giving me problem so I used `+` directly). But for now, I am happy that it finally worked :)

Comment: @Sourabh glad to hear!